# HTML5 Canvas, GUI

Tags: user-interface, html, canvas

I am have question about HTML5 Canvas GUI,(Sorry, I am newbie in HTML5, JavaScript)
How to create in HTML5 Canvas Graphical User Interface? can add in Canvas HTML Button's, Text Input and ... or something like? or maybe is better method create GUI in Canvas? or don't create in HTML5 Canvas GUI and create only something like Game map's, Sprite's, Character's Movement and other's?

Sorry my English is too is not very good. :-)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to StackOverflow Vyh.

This is a question and answer site for specific programming related questions.

This question is too open, please refer to basic tutorials like:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/canvas_tutorial

or

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/canvas.html#divingin

Don't hesitate to come back whenever you have a question, about specific answers of the canvass itself, we'll be waiting for you! :)

Good luck!